# RESOLVED - Docker: mvn clean install dockerfile:build command throwing mvn not found error

Tags: docker, maven

I am new to the Docker. when I tried executing mvn clean install dockerfile:build, command failed with  mvn not found error. I verified over the net and couldn't find proper solution. so updating here so that some one will find help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with below steps:

Step 1 : Download Maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
Step 2: Extract and copy to  C:/Maven
Step 3 : set up maven_home in system variables MAVEN_HOME C:\Maven
Step5 : add to the path variable %MAVEN_HOME%\bin;
Step 6: close and open Docker quick start
Step 7 : mvn clean install dockerfile:build this command should run successfully now.

Happy Learning..